# Scrapy, Scraper not going through all links

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "dmoz"
allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
    "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
]    



def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="site-list-content"]/div[@class="site-item "]'):
    #for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="title-and-desc"]//div[@class="site-title"]/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="title-and-desc"]//a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('normalize-space(div[@class="title-and-desc"]//div[@class="site-descr "]/text())').extract()
        yield item
```

That is the code for my scraper. I followed the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) on the scrapy website, but the code was a little bit outdated so I had to change the code myself. The code works with the /python/books site, but not with the /resources one. Can anyone provide an explanation as to why this happens? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? What are the symptoms? Any errors?

Comment: Also, if possible, I'd like for someone to show me how I can make my code more efficient - if there is a way.

Comment: @alecxe It only yields the results of /python/books, but no results from the second URL.

Comment: Interesting. If I run [this](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/163c7360b025184dc604bd51411b65b5) with scrapy, I get 4 items extracted.

Comment: @alecxe when I run, I get all results from the page.

Comment: What I suspect is that you're getting confused with CrawlSpider and Spider